# Where is R.sublime-build in macOS

Tags: r, macos, sublimetext3, sublimetext, macos-sierra

Considering [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124904/sublime-r-plot-closes-immediatally?noredirect=1#comment69468440_41124904).

I Would like to know where is `R.sublime-build`? If I understand it correctly, this file is used by Sublime Build System, to deal with R programming language, and must be somewhere but I cannot find it in macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages are installed in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3`. There you will find two folders, *Installed Packages* for zipped packages (`.sublime-package`) and *Packages* for extracted packages.

I recommend using the [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) to extract files from installed packages. Once installed, follow these steps:

1. Launch *PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource* from the [command palette](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/command_palette.html#how-to-use-the-command-palette)
2. Browse for the R package
3. Select `R.sublime-build` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This will extract the file to the `Packages` folder and open it in the editor. You can now make changes and save the file. Changes will be immediately available. However, upgrading a package might overwrite your changes.